# android - Creating and using ViewBinder inside a RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my app, there is an Activity which has a RecyclerView inside, which loads the list of options needed for that screen.
In the code below, i tried to implement a binder, which is needed because of the recent Android changes.

However, when i open the activity starts, the application crashes, throwing this error, linking the line with `binding = ItemSettingsBinding.bind(binding.root)`:

> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property binding has not been initialized

**What am i doing wrong? What's the correct way to implement a binder inside an adapter?**

`AdapterSettings.kt`

```
class AdapterSettings(
        var settingsList: List<DataItemSettings>,
        var listener: OnItemClickListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterSettings.SettingsViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var binding: ItemSettingsBinding

    inner class SettingsViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
            val position : Int = adapterPosition
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                listener.OnItemClick(position)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SettingsViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_settings, parent, false)
        return SettingsViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return settingsList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SettingsViewHolder, position: Int) {
        binding = ItemSettingsBinding.bind(binding.root)

        holder.itemView.apply {
            binding.rvTitle.text = settingsList[position].stringTitle
            binding.rvDescription.text = settingsList[position].stringDescription
            binding.rvIcon.setImageResource(settingsList[position].itemIcon)
        }
    }

    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun OnItemClick(position: Int)
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to create a binding in `onBindViewHolder`. There will be a binding for each itemview

Comment: Don't you have to inflate the binding first? I don't see that in your code. The `lateinit` property of `ItemsSettingsBinding` is never initialized in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is indeed another way to ViewBind in an adapter.

First, we need to setup the ViewHolder in a different way:

```
inner class SettingsViewHolder(private val binding: ItemSettingsBinding):
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root), View.OnClickListener {
```

With this, we created a binding value inside the brackets, so we are able to call the items of the actual view or layout trough `binding.root`

Inside the viewholder, we need to create a function used to bind our items. We can either bind like this:

```
fun bind(item: Item) {
    binding.item = item
    binding.executePendingBindings() 
}
```

Or like this:

```
fun bind(item: DataItemSettings) {
    binding.rvTitle.text = settingsList[position].stringTitle
    binding.rvDescription.text = settingsList[position].stringDescription
    binding.rvIcon.setImageResource(settingsList[position].itemIcon)
}
```

**NOTICE: 'getter for position: Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java.**

And, final step, we need to write this, inside `bindViewHolder`:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SettingsViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(settingsList[position])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're missing your inflate in onCreateViewHolder:

```
// Pseudo-Code
 override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SettingsViewHolder {
        val binding = ItemSettingsBinding
            .inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return SettingsViewHolder(binding)
    }
```

Then you can make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

Create the binding in `onCreateViewHolder` and pass the binding into the `ViewHolder` instead of the inflated `View`. Thus you create a binding for each created view and only need to do the `apply` stuff in the `onBindViewHolder`

Example:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SettingsViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_settings, parent, false)
    val binding = ItemSettingsBinding.bind(view)
    return SettingsViewHolder(binding)
}


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SettingsViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.binding.apply {
        rvTitle.text = settingsList[position].stringTitle
        rvDescription.text = settingsList[position].stringDescription
        rvIcon.setImageResource(settingsList[position].itemIcon)
    }
}
```

Adapt your `ViewHolder` accordingly